# Tbb-parallelized convolution of images with different depths

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I want to use tbb (parallel_for pattern) for concurrently convolution a large amount of images - each processor's core `convolves` single image. However, image's depth varies: either `monograyscale(1-channel)`, or `stereograyscale(2-channel)`, or `monorgb(3-channel)`, or `stereorgb(6-channel)`, etc.

It turns out that the workloads on different threads(cores) keeps changing. How to use correctly parallel_for in this task, or I should consider other parallel patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tbb::parallel_for of the form parallel_for(first,last,lambda) does some load balancing.  You might try it first.  Though it has a heuristic for guessing a good grainsize that can be fooled on occasion.

For best load balancing, possibly at the expense of extra per-iteration overhead, use a range-based tbb::parallel_for with a grainsize of 1 and a simple_partitioner.  That forces each iteration to run as a separate task, thus giving the TBB runtime maximum flexibility to rebalance load.  Below is a sample that executes 100 iterations, each with a random delay.

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    tbb::parallel_for(
        tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,100,1),  // Interval [0,100) with grainsize==1
        [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r) {
            for( int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i ) {
                printf("%d\n",i);
                usleep(random()%1000000);
            }
        },
        tbb::simple_partitioner());
}
```